# Graphics disappear when zoom in

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Recently I have this really weird bug : 
I have a new graphics-layer, that I build on runtime, with a point-graphic in it.
On higher extent - ever thing's great, on lower extent (zoom-in) the graphic disappears.

I found, while debugging, that the graphics "_shape" & "_offsets" properties are **null** when it disappears.

I also noticed that the layer's properties "minSacle" & "maxScale" are both **0** and "visibleAtMapScale" & "visible" are **true**.

Beside that, everything looks as usual - the graphic stays visible and at the layer's graphics array.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you change the graphic's geometry properties manually rather than using the graphic's [setGeometry()](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/graphic-amd.html#setgeometry) method.

For example, let's say you create a point graphic:

```
var graphic = new Graphic(new Point(point), symbol));            
map.graphics.add(graphic);
```

Then later you modify the geometry's `x` and `y` values.

```
graphic.geometry.x = newX;
graphic.geometry.y = newY;
map.graphics.redraw();
```

This approach *seems* to work fine until you start zooming or panning. Whenever you move to an extent that does not include the graphic's initial point, the graphic disappears. So `setGeometry()` must call additional code for everything to work properly.